# Appium desktop with webhook log

Tags: java, automated-tests, appium

How can I  use webhook log option in appium-desktop?
In appium server I can add an arg "--webhook localhost:9876" but I cant find this option in appium-desktop app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution found in appium-desktop is to create a new session and point your session to the local Appium under the Custom Server tab.

https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/issues/398#issuecomment-361782318